# Coolant leak - 4g63 sohc 2.0L non turbo

Tags: coolant, mitsubishi, leak, overheating, galant

Recently I was experiencing coolant leaks in between the engine block and the wheel on the passenger side. This only occurs after the car has been driven aggressively and once the car slightly overheated (around 60 - 75%) due to this.

**FYI** Prior to this issue, I was having a major radiator leak and I replaced the radiator. This also, I got to know after the car overheated badly and stalled. The mechanic said there is no symptom of a blown head gasket.

My car is a **2003 Mitsubishi Galant (4g63 2.0L sohc non turbo) RHD**.

I just need to verify the most likely areas this leak might come from you experts before I take it to the garage so that I can be 100% sure he is not ripping me off.

Thank you very much :)

This is my first car and I sometimes miss these routine checks. I have now learnt my lesson the hard way :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer anyone who runs across such an issue, the culprit of this cause was the (radiator/ coolant) hose that runs to the engine block. on the day car overheated, the end of the hose got burnt bad and sprung a leak. I got the hose replaced and no more leaks :)